# What is the disadvantages of naming react component files with hyphen-delimited names?

Tags: reactjs, coding-style, naming, rules

I'm wondering why is that everybody seems to name react component files with a starting capital letter and other js files with camelcase style? Isn't it better to name all the files with hyphen-delimited names, and the type of files can still be judged from its extension name?

What's the real advantages of adopting the former naming pattern?

Comment: It's just personal preference...

Comment: Custom component names must start with a capital letter. So this gets carried over into the file name. e.g. you can't do this: `<app />`. It must be `<App />`. That said, file names, and folder structure is personal preference.

Answer (score -1):

Components are a 'class' (I use that word carefully as it is just syntactic sugar) and convention dictates that a class is named with a starting capital letter. In the end what matters is that others can easily read and understand your code, so choose one style and stick to it.

As @jzm points out, you must use capital letters for your component classes. Thanks for the pick up.